# Two or more forms on 1 page doesn't post images

Tags: php, html

Very strange item, i have 2 forms on 1 page. If i post the first on the page the image is in the array but if i let the first form empty and fill the second the images are not posted.

What do i do wrong?!?!

```
<form name="test4" action="wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform4" class="comment-form show_info" data-abide enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="pmg_comment_avatar4" id="avatar-upload" />
..........
</form>

<form name="test5" action="wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform5" class="comment-form show_info" data-abide enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="pmg_comment_avatar5" id="avatar-upload" />
..........
</form>
```

Comment: you should add your backend code as well

Comment: Please change the id of the second input file element.

Comment: Where are your submit buttons?

Comment: Works correct @SahilPatel , but an id effected on a post?! Thats new for me :( Can you please give it as an awnser?

Comment: id shouldnt be affecting the posts. How are you submitting these forms?

Comment: @Amit jquery form submit

Comment: Yeah that would make difference if you were submitting the form using jquery.

Comment: Ahhh, i didn't know, learningcurve ;) Amit Joshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:** You should change the id of the second input file element.

*Why?*

The `id` attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

An element's unique identifier can be used for a variety of purposes, most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a document using fragment identifiers, as a way to target an element when scripting, and as a way to style a specific element from CSS.

Please read more about ID from [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html)